# Sobrecarga de constructores en TypeScript

Tags: typescript, sobrecarga, constructor

Estoy tratando de realizar una clase en TypeScript, de la siguiente forma :

Puede recibir un `Array<Array<string>>` unicamente o puede recibir varios parámetros (`ancho : number`, `blanco : string` , `trozo : string`)

La implementación me sugiere utilizar la `sobrecarga de constructores`, pero esto supone un problema ya que **en TypeScript los constructores creados deben ser compatibles**, así pues debemos implementar los constructores con todas las variables de clase aunque no se necesiten explicitamente en ese constructor, aunque se pueden declarar opcionales (De hecho se implementa un constructor que es compatible con todos los demás, los otros constructores simplemente se declaran):

**[PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/OYmlKwMXeD1E7jdTigz6?p=preview)**

```
class Piramide {
    public array :  Array<Array<String>> | Array<any>;
    public ancho : number;
    public blanco : string;
    public trozo : string;

    constructor(array : Array<Array<String>> | Array<any>, ancho? : number, blanco? : string, trozo? : string);
    constructor(array :  Array<Array<String>> | Array<any>, ancho : number, blanco : string, trozo : string){

        if(!array){
            this.ancho = ancho;
            this.blanco = blanco;
            this.trozo = trozo;
            this.array = [];
        }
        else 
            this.array = array;
            this.ancho = array.length;
            ...
    }

    ...
}
```

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto más comprensible y legible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La siguiente forma se me hace limpia y simple:

```
class Piramide {

    constructor(
        public array?: string[][] | Array<any>,
        public ancho?: number,
        public blanco?: string,
        public trozo?: string
    ) {
        if(!array){
            this.ancho = ancho;
            this.blanco = blanco;
            this.trozo = trozo;
            this.array = [];
        }
        else
            this.ancho = array.length;
            ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se podria simular una "sobrecarga de contructor" comprobando el tipo de dato en el constructor.

```js
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;
}

interface IUserRaw {
  UserName: string;
  UserLastName: string;
}

function isUserRaw(user): user is IUserRaw {
  return !!(user.UserName && user.UserLastName);
}

class User {
  name: string;
  lastName: string;

  constructor(data: IUser | IUserRaw) {
    if (isUserRaw(data)) {
      this.name = data.UserName;
      this.lastName = data.UserLastName;
    } else {
      this.name = data.name;
      this.lastName = data.lastName;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una interface, la cual es más flexible a la hora de declarar parámetros opcionales. Se puede usar tanto como parámetro que recibe el constructor, como prototipo de la clase que la implementa :

**[PLUNK](https://plnkr.co/edit/DdMafAHTfV67yYmmEZTk?p=preview)**

```
interface IPiramide {
    array? : Array<Array<string>>,
    ancho? : number,
    blanco? : string,
    trozo?  : string
}

class Piramide implements IPiramide {

    constructor(piramide : IPiramide){

        if(piramide.array){
            this.array = piramide.array;
            this.ancho = piramide.array.length;
        }
        else {
            this.array = [];
            this.ancho = piramide.ancho;
            this.blanco = piramide.blanco;
            this.trozo = piramide.trozo;
        }

    }
}
```